# Express.js: Set cache-control header for static assets bundled in webpack

Tags: reactjs, express, caching, webpack

I can't figure out how to set a Cache-Control header for static assets using express.js and webpack.

In my react app I'm including static images as follows:

```
 <img src={require("./images/Logo.png")} alt="Logo"/>
```

I have a loader in my webpack.config.js that outputs images to /public/images

```
module: {
    loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.png/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=public/images/[name].[ext]'
     }]
}
```

Finally, I mark the /public folder in server.js as containing static assets and set the Cache-Control header

```
const server = express();
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {maxAge: "30d"}));
```

The problem is that `require()` resolves the path including /public folder:

```
<img class="full-width" src="/public/images/Logo.png" alt="Logo">
```

but `express` expects a URL without the `public/` part.

Is there a way to force `express.static()` to include the `/public` in its path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to force `express.static()` to include the `/public` in its path?

Absolutely:

```
server.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {maxAge: "30d"}));
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and while the static assets are server from `/public/images` URL, the Cache-Control header is not there. I need a solution where static assets would have this header

Comment: Works for me: `Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000`

Comment: I've tried it on a separate project and indeed it does work. The problem must be somewhere else. Thanks for your help!